# How to unset the title of a custom form field

Tags: theming, 8

I'm trying to unset the label of a custom form called email. In which the value is in the #title key.

I've tried `{{ value|without('title', 'description', 'email.#title') }}`

But it is not working

Answer (score 0):

@Fazeela Abu Zohra try to unset the value in **.theme** file. write a form alter and kint $form variable .Find your label value

```
function est_form_alter( &$form, &$form_state, $form_id ) { 
  if($form_id == 'your_form_id'){
    kint($form);
  }
```

and then simply unset the variable.

```
unset($form['form_id']['#value']);
```

Here,i assume you find your variable at $form['form_id']['#value'].Hope it  will be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a custom form you're building from your code then just set the field's title as empty string:

```
$form['email']['#title'] = '';
```

If the form is a node form then implement Drupal's hook_form_alter like this:

```
function MODULE_NAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'FORM_ID') {
    $form['field_email']['und']['#title'] = '';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in **Drupal 8**, you can use hook_form_FORM_ID_alter hook function in your THEME.theme file.

For exemple with theme named *custom* and FORM_ID named *contact_message_custom_contact_form* :

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function custom_form_contact_message_custom_contact_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  unset($form['field_contact_name']['widget'][0]['value']['#title']);
  unset($form['field_contact_message']['widget'][0]['value']['#title']);
  unset($form['field_contact_phone']['widget'][0]['value']['#title']);
  unset($form['field_contact_mail']['widget'][0]['value']['#title']);
}
```